# Speical character is not working in spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have implemented **spring i18n** to support multiple languages using **spring MVC 4.1.4** but few special character **are not working for spring validator** and **same character are working fine in simple JSP page**.
Special character like: **é,à,ê.**.

I am using spring messages in JSP like below

```
<spring:message code="sample.message" var="tooltip"/>
```

Above message in properties file:

```
**For English:**
sample.message=Access Denied!! You are not allowed to access system from this IP address

**For French**
sample.message=Acc\u00E8s refus\u00E9!! Vous n\'\u00EAtes pas autoris\u00E9 \u00E0 acc\u00E9der au syst\u00E8me \u00E0 partir de cette adresse IP
```

**For Spring validation using JAVA**

```
public class TestValidator  implements Validator {

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

public String getMessage(String key, Object[] arguments){
        try {
            return messageSource.getMessage(key, arguments, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Using above code I am doing spring validation for mandatory fields with form submit event but its showing **?** in jsp front end error message.

**Can anyone help for the same?**

Comment: what kind of encoding you're using in your pages? is it utf-8?

Comment: Yes I am using UTF-8.